# adding google map to android, difference between android platform vs google api?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

If I've already started an Android 2.3.3 platform and I have lots of code, how do I add a google map to my application? Do I really need to have the Google API? What is the difference?

I've added this to my manifest

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Is this enough? I tried extending my class with `MapActivity` but doesn't work.

Do I even need this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, yes, you need the Google API version.
The reason for this is that the stock Android API does not come with the functionality such as Google Maps (and others, but I can't think of any at the moment).
This is the reason why, even though you added a reference to the library, your project is failing to compile. It simply can't find the library as it's part of the Google Apis.

Just change your build target to the Google API version of 2.3.3, and you should be fine. All other Android functionality is present in it, along with some other useful things so it's always a wise decision to use the Google API version by default. In my opinion at least, please correct me if there are downsides to doing this.